# how to compute a general lower bound of min-max regret for expert advice problem

Tags: optimization, computer-science, machine-learning

In the book,  Prediction, Learning, and Games, chapter 3, section 7(General lower bound), page 59. theorem 3.6 compute a  lower bound for min-max regret.
min-max regret is:
$$V_{n}^{(N)}=\inf _{P} \sup _{\{\mathcal{F}:|\mathcal{F}|=N\}} \sup _{y^{n} \in \mathcal{Y}^{n}} \max _{i=1, \ldots, N} \sum_{t=1}\left(\ell\left(\widehat{p}_{t}, y_{t}\right)-\ell\left(f_{i, t}, y_{t}\right)\right)$$
such that $p$ is prediction  of algorithm and $f_{i,t} \in \mathcal{F}$,  $N$ is number of expert and $n$ is  Number of steps for implementing the algorithm.
In this theorem like to compute
$$V_{n\left\lfloor\log _{2} N\right\rfloor}^{(N)} \geq\left\lfloor\log _{2} N\right\rfloor V_{n}^{(2)}$$

What is the idea behind proof of this theorem?
and why do we consider the expert advice as a sequence of zeros and ones?